Can I personalize the my transactional email without saving json payload to a data extension?
I need to send transactional email from sfmc, my stakeholder doesn't want to use data extension while sending transactional email but how can I personalize my email without having the json data in a data extension? Is there any way to parse json payload without saving it to a data extension?

Data extension is required, that's just how the platform works. Why does your stakeholder not want that?
